# Pass ArrayList Item from one Fragment to another one

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, fragment

i need help over here.

So i am building an Android app with two Fragments. (General and Favorites)
The General Fragments has a list of items, on these items there is a Star, So what i want to do is when the user clicks on the Star of the ListView Item, that Item to be then shown in the ListView of the Favorites Fragment.

So copying Items from a ListView to another ListView in another Fragment.

I am using an Adapter for the General Fragment to fill it with items.

The Variables on the ListView Items are just an TextView(Title) and an ImageView(Poster)

Here is the MainActivity class where also the Interface is implementet, i am using bottom navigation drawers, to switch between different Fragments. The Interface Method is at the end.

Here is the Main Activity method used from interface:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GW3Q.png)

Comment: Read up on implementing an interface. You could pass the details of your list item via this, from General to Favourites.

Comment: Pass data as arraylist through intent should work.

Comment: Use Parceable: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html.  Make  the custom class implemnents parceable and pass the array list in Bundle.

Answer (score 2):

Receive the list like this then put it into listview

```
ArrayList<GroupListDetail> results;
try {
        results = (ArrayList<GroupListDetail>) getIntent()
                .getSerializableExtra("mylist");
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }


if ((results != null) && results.size() > 0) {
        listView.setAdapter(new GroupListAdapter(this, results));
    }
```

Add and Pass the list like this

```
myList = new ArrayList<GroupListDetail>();
for(int a = 0; a<myList2.size();a++)
{
 GroupListDetail gld = new GroupListDetail();
 gld.setItem_ID(myList2.get(a).getItem_ID());
 myList.add(gld);
}

    Intent i = new Intent(GroupList.this, Gscanner.class);
            if ((results != null) && results.size() > 0) {
                i.putExtra("mylist", results);
            }
```

Details.java

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GroupListDetail implements Serializable{

     public String getItem_ID() {
     return Item_ID;
     }
     public void setItem_ID(String Item_ID) {
     this.Item_ID = Item_ID;
     }
     private String Item_ID ;
}
```

Comment: you can implement Paceable instead of Serializable . This http://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/parcelable-vs-java-serialization-in-android-app-development  might make it a bit clear why parceable is better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BroadCast` or `EventBus` for this. Here is [link of EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).In my opinion,EventBus is more easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same adapter to populate the list on General and Favorites List Fragment. You can use the enum Mode { General , Favorite }
to show the respective list.

You can have a boolean flag( isFavorite)  with each list item. 
Initially you can have the value of isFavorite as false.

In OnClickItem listener of general list just toggle that flag to true for particular item.

In General list populate the list with isFavorite to false ( in case if you don't want to show favorite item in that list )  and in Favorite list populate the list where isFavorite is set to true.

Similarly you can toggle from favorite list to general list.

Comment: Since im new to Android do you think you could help me by writing the code? 
I would appreciate that, 
Thank you.

Comment: Sure can you post some initial draft ? i can help you with it.